# Action script set popup window position to center of sceen

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, popup, position

I make advance data grid to view tabulate data. Each row has icon. When user click that icon show extra data for the that row.

I want show popup in my page center. I used `PopUpManager.centerPopUp(panel);` to do it. This is my code sample.

```
panel = new TitleWindow();
panel.showCloseButton = true;
panel.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE,closeHelp);
panel.addChild(txt);                                
PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, Application.application.linkbody, false);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(panel);
```

Now pop up show in center of hole page but not screen. When data grid have more data popup window is hide. I want show it center of screen. How can i do it. Can i set popup position manually? Please help me.

Comment: What is Application.application.linkbody?

Comment: Application.application.linkbody is mx:VBox that include the content which has changing content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the position manually, or change the parent to center it in your application.

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, Application.application as DisplayObjectContainer, false);
```

`PopUpManager.centerPopUp` centers the popup on its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would think `PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, this, false);` should do it. If not, try `PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, Application.application, false);`